# How do I add a local project to a new Repo with the Mac PlasticSCM client?

Tags: plasticscm

I created a new Repo successfully, and created a new local view, and pointed it to my existing project folder. It created the .plastic hidden folder successfully.

But when I look at pending changes, it doesn't see anything, and I don't know how to push the existing files into the repo. No matter how much I refresh, it doesn't show my existing files.

If I go to Workspace Explorer, it shows the directory to the project, with a red minus icon on it.

I've never had this problem creating a new repo and adding existing files on Windows... not sure how to do it on Mac, because the client is completely different and I can't find any tutorials on the Internet for the Mac client.

Comment: The workspace will be initially empty, but if you copy files/folders in this path and then refresh the "Workspace Explorer", you should be able to add and commit them. From the "Pending changes" view --> Options --> Enable "Show private items"  and "Show checked-out items". If the folder has a red icon, it means that it's already added to source control so it should appear in the "Pending Changes" view. The Mac workflow is the same as Windows.

Comment: If the issue persists I think it's better if you reach us at: support at codicesoftware dot com and we will review your setup in detail.